# dual boot windows and Ubuntu, BUT make windows invisible to Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, security

I would like to regularly run an application that requires software that I am not comfortable running on the same machine I pay my bills on. I can install a second SSD and dual boot Ubuntu to run it. Is there a way I can protect the Windows side from the Ubuntu side? I need the performance so VMs are not an option.

Comment: No protection required. When dual-booting you're only booting one OS at any given time.

Comment: Ubuntu probably can't write to NTFS natively [though I'm not a nix expert]. You could also look into using `fstab` to prevent your other drives from mounting at all.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - not being booted in itself will not prevent writing to any/all other drives.

Comment: Ubuntu has native support for NTFS since a long time ago. That doesn't mean it mounts any NTFS partition automatically. It especially does NOT mount Windows system partitions. It won't write anything to any drive unless explicitly mounted and told to write something to the mounted partition by the user. Ubuntu by itself won't do nothing that isn't told to do by the user. This is all baseless fears and assumptions ad a totally false "problem" from the start.

Comment: Always better safe than sorry - we have no clue what this software is, nor what it may attempt to do - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions for help with fstab

Comment: @Tetsujin, Ubuntu since at lease 18.04 most definitely *can* write to NTFS, though it will avoid doing so if the partition is "dirty", e.g. contains *hiberfile.sys* that must be left untouched to avoid trashing Windows on reboot. In essence, unless a user *intentionally forces* the NTFS partition to be mounted writable, Windows should be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though a newer version (at least since 18.04 LTS) of Ubuntu *can* write to NTFS, it will not be able to do so *by default* if that partition is "dirty", e.g. contains *hiberfile.sys* that must be left untouched to avoid trashing Windows on reboot.

However, [a user can *intentionally force* the NTFS partition to be mounted writable](https://www.maketecheasier.com/write-windows-partition-linux/). This requires specific action by the user. Consider that, once someone has physical control of a PC, there are **many** ways to modify or even damage the Windows partitions, such as booting from USB with Win RE (AKA "WinPE").

Having Ubuntu on another partition is not what I consider a security issue. If there are other users, don't give them logon privileges in Ubuntu. If you have concerns about making accidental changes, just [change automatic mounting of Window partition(s) to read-only](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/mount-ntfs-linux).